# Expected value of X given Y=2 using geometric progression

Tags: statistics

A fair die is rolled repeatedly. Let X be the number of rolls needed to obtain a 5 and Y is the number of rolls needed to obtain a $6$. Calculate the Expected value of X given Y = 2.

I have read few posts on this. However, I still am not able to understand the methods used in those posts to get to the final answer. This is how I approached the problem after getting some ideas from some discussions about the topic.

> Let P(X) be the conditional distribution of X given Y=2
>   P(1) = 5 on first roll; 6 on second =(($\frac 16$^2))
>   P(2) = 5 on second roll(impossible since Y=2) =0
>   P(3) = no 5 or 6 on the first roll; 6 on the second roll; 5 on third roll
>   =($\frac 23$ )($\frac 16$ ^2)
>   P(4) = no 5 or 6 on first roll; 6 on second roll; no 5 on third roll; 5 on the fourth roll
>   =$\frac 23$ ($\frac 16$ ^2)($\frac 56$ )
>   
>   E[X given Y=2]
>  
>   =1(($\frac 16$ ^2)) + 2(0) +3[($\frac 23$) ($\frac 16$ ^2)] + 4[($\frac 23$ )(($\frac 16$ )^2)($\frac 56$ )] +5[($\frac 23$ )(($\frac 16$ )^2)(($\frac 56$ ^2)] + ........../P(Y=2)
>   
>   =(($\frac 16$ )^2)[1 + 3(($\frac 23$ ) +4(2/3)(5/6) + 5(($\frac 23$ )((5/6)^2) + ........../P(Y=2)]
>   =(($\frac 16$)^2)[1+ (($\frac 23$ )[3+4(($\frac 56$ ) +5((($\frac 56$ )^2) +............../P(Y=2)]

Okay. So, at this point, I have an infinite geometric series where a=3 and r=5/6. The sum of this infinite series would be a/(1-r) which is 18. However, the correct sum should be 48 and the rest of the solution goes like this:

> =(($\frac 16$)^2[1+ (($\frac 23$ )[48]] / (($\frac 5/36)
>   =(33/36)/(5/36) = 33/5 = 6.6

Can someone explain to me the final steps? And if there is a better alternative to this solution, could you please share it to me? Thanks. Help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \sum_{i=0}^\infty (3+i) \left( \frac56\right)^i
\\&= \sum_{i=0}^\infty 3 \left( \frac56\right)^i+\sum_{i=0}^\infty i \left( \frac56\right)^i\\
&= 18 + 6\sum_{i=0}^\infty i \left( \frac56\right)^i \left( \frac16\right)\\ 
&=18 + 6 \left( \frac56\right)\sum_{i=0}^\infty i \left( \frac56\right)^{i-1} \left( \frac16\right)\\ 
&=18+5 \left( \frac{1}{\frac16} \right)\\
&=18+5(6)\\
&=48
\end{align}

Notice that $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty i\left( \frac56 \right)^{i-1}\left( \frac16 \right)$$

is the mean of geometric distribution with success probability $\frac16$.

Comment: I reached to the point where I could get the series from my method and from lulu's method. However, I could not figure out how you solved the series. Could you explain a bit further or recommend me some readings to understand it better. Thank you!

Comment: first equality: $4=3+1$, $5=3+2$, $6=3+3, \ldots$.
second equality: the first series is geometric sum, and then I multiply and divide by $6$ for the second series.
Third equality: I take out $\frac56$ and multiply it with $6$, resulting in $5$.
Fourth equality, recognizing that it is just the mean of geometric distributions.

Comment: I have rewritten the answer using sigma notation. Hopefully that is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Method I (recursive):  Absent the constraint, we know the answer is $6$.

Given the constraint, you get a $5$ on the first roll with probability $\frac 15$ (since we know you don't get a $6$).  If you miss on the first roll, we roll again to get our $6$, at which point you expect it to take $6$ more rolls (as the constraint no longer has any force).  Thus the answer is $$E[X\,|\,Y=2]=\frac 15\times 1 +\frac 45 \times 8 = \frac {33}5 = 6.6$$

Method II (Geometric Series). We are only interested in those paths along which the first toss is not a $6$ and the second one is.  Among those paths, exactly $\frac 15$ start with $5$.  Thus the conditional probability, given $Y=2$, that $X=1$ is $P(X=1\,|\,Y=2)=\frac 15$.  As you remark, $P(X=2\,|\,Y=2)=0$. Above $2$ we have $$P(X=n\,|\,Y=2)=\frac 45 \times \left(\frac 56\right)^{n-3}\times \frac 16$$  It follows that $$E[X\,|\,Y=2]=\frac 15+\frac 16\times \frac 45\times \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} n\left(\frac 56\right)^{n-3}=\frac 15 + \frac 16\times \frac 45\times 48=6.6$$

Comment: okay. I got the second method until I got to the point where  \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} n\left(\frac 56\right)^{n-3}. I looked at how Siong solved the series, but did not have a slightest idea of what he did from the second step. How did he break the series into two? maybe I lack skill on solving series. Could you help me on this? Is there an alternative method? Thanks

Comment: Well, I don't speak for  the other writer, but that appears to be the standard algebraic method for computing $\sum nr^n$.  Personally, I prefer to differentiate:  we know $\sum x^n=\frac 1{1-x}$ so $\sum nx^{n-1}=\frac 1{(1-x)^2}$ and  $\sum nx^{n}=\frac x{(1-x)^2}$.

Comment: Just to stress:  I greatly prefer the recursive method (Method I).  Avoids all the series completely.